# Uniformly calling -> or . in templated code with C++20 concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

In template code I want to detect if something is a pointer(this includes smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`) or value and then call `->some_func()` or `.some_func()`.

I know the name of `some_func`, but sometimes people pass me pointers, sometimes they pass me values(and this is a fixed requirement, long story, but I can not just ask people to use `*` at callsite).

So this is what I came up with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <memory>

template<typename T> 
auto& get_dotable(T& t){
    if constexpr (requires{*t;}) {
        return *t;
    } else{ 
        return t;
    }
};

void fn()
{
    auto sps=std::make_shared<std::string>("abc");
    auto csps=std::make_shared<const std::string>("abc");
    auto ups=std::make_unique<std::string>("abc");
    auto os=std::optional<std::string>("abc");
    std::cout << get_dotable(sps).size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << get_dotable(csps).size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << get_dotable(ups).size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << get_dotable(os).size() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    fn();
}
```

I am fine with it blindly calling `*` on `std::optional` without checking if optional is engaged.

It does not work with temporaries, but I am fine with that since I fear lifetime issues, although it prevents some nice usecases like:

```
std::cout << get_dotable(ups.get()).size() << std::endl;
```

Apart from these issues that I'm fine with, is there some problem with this solution, and is there a better way to do it instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Is the solution you came up with not working?

Comment: @cigen  It *seems* to be working, but I am not really confident to say it is working.

Comment: Should the parameter be `T&& t`?

Comment: A class can overload both `operator.` and `operator->` this will probable confuse everything.

Comment: @Eljay I think I want to avoid that since I dont want lifetime issues, but not sure

Comment: @RichardCritten You can overload `operator.` ??

Comment: @eerorika ah yes, Bjarne wants to add that, but it is impossible as of now :)

Comment: The *requires* clause can be simplified to `if constexpr (requires{ *t; })`.

Comment: If you know the names of the functions you're calling it might be better to implement `get_dotable` with testing for those functions like `requires{ t->some_func(); }`.

Comment: @IlCapitano well I want generic get_dotable that can be used in dozens of templates calling different member functions(they all know their names, but they are all different)

Comment: @康桓瑋 thank you, updated code, it never crossed my mind that t is "captured" I always assumed you must have that fake arguments signature to get it.

Answer (score 1):

> It does not work with temporaries

This can be fixed easily by using forwarding references.

---

Your attempt differs significantly from your description. In your description, you want to differentiate pointers from "values" (which is somewhat confusing since pointers are values too) while your attempt differentiates things that have unary operator `*` and those that don't.

Considering that sometimes the intention is to call member function of the passed object and sometimes the intention is to indirect through the passed object to call the member function of the referred object, there is high chance of confusion when the caller intends to call a member function of the class that has the indirection operator. Example: `get_dotable(ups).get()`.

The described premise of treating pointers differently (from non-pointers) doesn't have this problematic confusion because pointers don't have members. It can probably be implemented with concepts as well, but overloads work too:

```
template<typename T> 
T&& get_dotable(T&& t){
    return t;
};
template<typename T> 
T& get_dotable(T* t){
    return *t;
};
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, for me this works as expected, but maybe I misunderstood your answer, or we disagree on what is expected. https://godbolt.org/z/enx7xEnYK

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The problem is when the user expects `std::unique_ptr::get`  to be called, because the function usually calls `obj.get()` when a `obj` is passed.

Comment: For me that behavior is expected, but I guess it could be confusing to some... thank you for the answer.

Comment: also thank you for C++17(14?) option, I think it may even be nicer than requires one, but I am a bit torn on that one...  I like the ad-hoc requires stuff, but I think your code is superior since for values it works on temporaries when it comes to values.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl It's C++11 now that I removed auto return type.

Comment: These two templates are what I came up with originally as well.  May need a few more specializations for special handling of std::optional, std::shared_ptr, and std::unique_ptr.  And maybe check for nullptr or !has_value and throw (...?) when the Bad Thing happens.  Could also throw for nullptr for the T* case.

Comment: Ah, this does not work for my usecase, I need to also work on smart pointers... sorry for not being explicit, but in my defense I can say that example code contains shared/unique_ptr  I will edit my question.